# fold / unfold form fields in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started with Angular and have lots of doubts. Right now I have a form with several fields, check image:

[image]

I want to include a link under Keywords Label-input field, something like "Advanced" and if clicked then Must not include and Must include form fields fold / unfold, or appear/dissapear.

That said, I'm not sure if I have to use ng-show or ng-hide in the fields to be shown / hidden and then use ng-click on the "Advanced" link to make change their status. Something like this for instance:

```
    <div class="cg">
        <label class="cl">Keywords</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="id_search"
                   ui-select2 = "{multiple: true, simple_tags: true, tags: []}"
                   />
             <div class="qs"
                  popover-placement="left"
                  popover-trigger="mouseenter"
                  popover="Type your search"></i></div>
            <a ng-click="changeStatus()">Advanced</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cg" ng-show="form_element.status">
        <label class="cl">Must not include</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="id_must_not_include"
                   class="input-block-level"
                   ng-disabled="tagItem.perm == 'r'"
                   ui-select2 = "{multiple: true, simple_tags: true, tags: []}"
                   ng-model="not_include"/>
            <div class="qs"
                 ng-show="is_modal"
                 tooltip="Must not include words."
                 tooltip-placement="left"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></div>
            <span class="help-block" ng-hide="is_modal"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cg" ng-show="form_element.status">
        <label class="cl">Must include</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="id_must_include"
                   class="input-block-level"
                   ng-disabled="tagItem.perm == 'r'"
                   ui-select2 = "{multiple: true, simple_tags: true, tags: []}"
                   ng-model="must_include"/>
            <div class="qs"
                 ng-show="is_modal"
                 tooltip="Must include words."
                 tooltip-placement="left"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></div>
            <span class="help-block" ng-hide="is_modal"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Should I use a different approach? Some help would be great!

Thanks!
Alejandro

**NOTE: For other people in similar situation, check [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/huvecami/1/edit?html,css,js) to see how to do this**

Comment: Your example looks 100%. Use ngShow pointing to a field like formElement.shouldShow and toggle this boolean value using ngClick using either function inside your controller as in your example, or `ng-click="formElement.shouldShow = !formElement.shouldShow"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there seems like it would work alright assuming the `changeStatus()` call would do something like: `is_modal = !is_modal;` You could definitely define your template a little more simply. For example, wrap both of the advanced fields in a single `div` with a single `ng-show="is_modal"` then you wouldn't have to deal with the extra span, but it just depends on what you're trying to accomplish with your markup...

But, it looks like what you have there should work just fine.

Comment: Both Jordan and your response are correct and lead me to the correct solution, thus, hard to determine which one is the correct answer. I will use FIFO strategy and just give it to you, but let other readers know that both are correct! I've edited my question with a link to a JSBin if anybody needs it

Comment: I'll do the same for kentcdodds.  We basically did the same thing from  different angles.  Code is awesome!  I would say both are 100% equal in function.

Answer (score 3):

Ng-show and ng-hide are used for manipulating the view as you would like.  The error most people do when starting angular is that they directly try to target content to show/hide instead of creating states of the form.  That state of the form is what will dictate the view of your form.  All of this can happen in your controller to keep it nice and readable  For example:

```
App.controller('Ctrl1', function Ctrl1 ($scope, TestService) {
    $scope.isAdvancedState = false;

    $scope.changeStatus = function() {
        $scope.isAdvancedState = true;
    }
});
```

You are totally on the right track with this.  Angular is a little strange at first but quickly becomes pretty amazing.  Stick with it :)

Thanks,

Jordan